# running 2 firebase databases in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I need to add an other database to my existing one in my angular 4 project. I'm using angularfire 2. I have an envirement.ts file that contains my firebase config file(API key, authDomain ...)

This is a part of my app.module.ts :

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../environment';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,   
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    ...
```

How can I add an independent database to my app?

Comment: Which kind of db do you want to add? do you want to add another firebase instance?

Comment: not a problem anymore after firestore